# How do I display Data from a node js sever to my html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

> This is what i got so far

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world'); //replace with your data here
});

app.listen(8888);
```

> the html

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="Link">


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#but').click(function(){
            $.get('http://localhost:8888/data', {}, function(data){
                $("#test").append(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just want to display the hello world inside the div can somebody please help?

Comment: did you import jquery?

Comment: Yeah its in the Head of the html

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the div to have the class named test.

Also, in some systems, using the port 8888 doesn't work.
Try 8080 instead.

Answer (score 0):

`.test` is a class selector. It matches 0 elements because none of your elements are a member of that class.

You have `<div id="test">`. An `id` is not a `class`.

An ID selector uses `#`, not `.`

Comment: Possibly also a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666) but you didn't mention any errors on the Console in your browser's developer tools.